# Email validation regex takes a long time to complete on medium-long strings

Tags: javascript, regex, backtracking

After returning true or false with:

```
return (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/.test(str));
```

Where str is testing123@testing123.testing123
it takes about 25 seconds to complete.

In general, shorter strings take less than 1 second.

This is most likely due to back-tracking. I am not very good with Regex, can someone help me reduce the time it takes to process an email. E.g. it must have letter(s) then @ then letter(s) then . then letter(s) and must not be too long.

Comment: 25 seconds? I can't beleive.

Comment: Have a look on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this won't match for the valid email `bob@accounting.americanexpress`. You shouldn't do more than just check if it contains an `@` and then have an email verification process, since a regular expression for emails is really hard.

Comment: I did have it allow 16 final chars instead of just 8, but yeah I need to improve it a lot.

Comment: Please see my finalized answer. Sorry to stop too early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
\S+@\S+
```

Or even (with anchors)

```
^\S+@\S+$
```

and actually **send an email** to that address rather than using a complicated, likely error-prone expression.

Comment: Maybe add start and end too.  `^\S+@\S+$`

Comment: @Keith: You might be missing several addresses then.

Comment: I'm assuming he's checking for 1 email, seen as he's using test.  And with him also say `str is testing123@testing123.testing123`

Comment: I think /\S+@\S+\.\S+/ is better. I will go with that, and send an email to see if there is a reply.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [RFC 2822 Standrard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) for matching emails. It can [match 99.9%](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) of emails out today.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

If you want to just catch syntax errors, you can simply use

```
\S+@\S+
```

Taken from one of the answers from [another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `?` after each `[.-]`:

```
/^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,8})+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rsr4SY/1/)

In `([.-]?\w+)*`, the `[.-]?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `.` or `-`, and the whole group pattern gets reduced to `(\w+)*` after `\w+`, it causes too many redundant backtracking steps.

Also, it is a good idea to use non-capturing groups if you are only using the grouping construct to quantify a group of subpatterns.

Now, regarding

> it must have letter(s) then @ then letter(s) then . then letter(s) and must not be too long

I see others suggest `^\S+@\S+\.\S+$` like solutions, which is a good idea, just make sure you understand that `\S` matches any char other than whitespace (not just *letters*). Besides, this does not actually provide the final solution since "must not be too long" condition is not met (`+` matches from 1 to quite many occurrences, that is why it is described as *1 or more*).

**I suggest using the pattern inside an HTML5 *pattern* attribute and restrict the number of chars a user can type with `maxlength` attribute**:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="\S+@\S+\.\S+" maxlength="256" title="Please enter an email address like name@myhost.com!" placeholder="name@myhost.com"/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

**NOTE**: the *pattern* regex is compiled by enclosing the pattern with `^(?:` and `)$`, you do not need to use `^` and `$` in the regex here. So, `pattern="\S+@\S+\.\S+"` is translated into:

- `^(?:` (this is added by HTML5) - start of a string (and a non-capturing group starts)
- `\S+` - any 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\S+` - any 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `\S+` - any 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `)$` (this is added by HTML5) - the non-capturing group ends and the end of a string is matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Regex` to check emails :

```
var emailregex = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

replace ()* with ()?
PS: Pretty weird expression to match emails:)

Answer (score 0):

An efficient method of matching emails is:

```
\S+@\S+\.\S+
```

It's short, matches almost any email, and won't match:

```
abc@abc
```

as some of these other answers might.